# PHP Dynamic Search Function

Tags: php, search

I want to create a dynamic search function with PHP and MySQL.
In the search form I have a selection field, customer categories, with multiple selection. After submitting the form, this multiple selection should be searched in the database. How can I realize this?

I have stored the result from the form for this field in an array. This contains the ID of the customer category, each ID has its own entry in the database.

```
[kat] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 11
    )
```

Comment: You can use the MySQL operator `IN` which handles multiple values: `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Thanks, good approach.
But how do I get the Id's into a variable to use the IN operator then?

Comment: @DennisMüller you can use implode("," , $yourArray); this functions would return something like this: "9,11"